# ¿ Cómo Cambiar el formato datepicker yy/mm/dd?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo mi función básica en Js para mostrar la fecha con datepicker

```
/*===============================
SELECCIONAR FECHA
===============================*/
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker();
```

y mi input en html para que me muestre el calendario e ir escogiendo la fecha

```
<label for="agregarFechaInicioPeriodoLectivo">Fecha de Inicio del Año Lectivo</label>
  <input type="text"
  name="agregarFechaInicioPeriodoLectivo"
  id="agregarFechaInicioPeriodoLectivo"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="2020-12-31"
  required data-toggle="datepicker">
```

pero al seleccionar la fecha en el input se imprime así `12/31/2020` cuando en la base de datos necesito que se guarde de esta manera 2020-12-31 mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que se imprima al mismo formato que requiere la base de datos con guion en vez de slash y que el formato sea año-mes-dia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede pasar el objeto de configuración como parámetro asignando el formato.

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });
```

Comment: Gracias hermano funciono correctamente